# Invalid literal for int() with base 16

Tags: python, string, subprocess

I have a problem with the below code. I am running python script to run exe and pass parameters to it. I get the below error:
ValueError invalid literal for int() with base 16:

However if i put an extra semi colon (which I don't need) after 0 and before double quote it will work. Is something wrong with my string?

```
program="C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe"
args='"21022019;A0A1A2A3A4A5A6A7;B0B1B2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9BABBBCBDBEBF;1;1982;0"-e fixed -k aa11bb22cc33dd44ee55ff6600112233 -f jf_Creds_python.hex'
subprocess.call([program,args])
```

This is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 249, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 53, in main 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '"21022019'
```

Comment: well in your question you're missing a closing single quote `'`

Comment: The double quote I am talking about above is before -e fixed

Comment: Sorry copy/paste error, I have single quote in my code after .hex

Comment: This is the full error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 249, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 53, in main
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '"21022019'

Comment: update the question with that information, don't include it as an comment

Comment: How would you call `program.exe` from the command line normally? There's either a problem with how you are specifying the argument(s), or with how `program.exe` parses its arguments, or both.

Comment: From the command line it would be run by calling >program_name followed by parameters as above in args. If I add semi colon after 0 and before double quote, it will run correctly but program will return error because parameters do not match as expected. Is it something to with my string format?

Comment: If I add or remove a semi colon within the double quotes, it will work with program.exe returning error that parameters are incorrect. Is there something restricting the semi colon on the string message?

Answer (score -1):

I have found a fix but do not really understand it.

```
program="C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe"
args='"21022019;A0A1A2A3A4A5A6A7;B0B1B2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9BABBBCBDBEBF;1;1982;0"-e fixed -k aa11bb22cc33dd44ee55ff6600112233 -f jf_Creds_python.hex'
subprocess.call([program,{args}])
```

If I place curly braces around args, it will be successful. It works now, but I'm not fully sure how it is working, if someone might explain it would be great?